# file_exists() inbuilt php function well defined i.e. ($filepath . $filename) but still remains unresponsive

Tags: php

I have tried hard coding the file path i.e.  `if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["document"]["name"]));`

I have also tried out the variable i.e.  `if (file_exists($folder . $_FILES["document"]["name"]));`

where `$folder = "uploads/";`

I have nested it inside the `if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))` because i want the uploaded file to be moved first into the `"uploads/"` folder where then the `if(file_exists....` can check if there already is a similar file and alerts the user. I feel its only logical to do so...other opinion is however welcome incase am not doing it right.

The entire code looks like this

```
<?php
  require("db.php");
  require("functions.php");

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  

      $ftype = $_FILES["document"]["type"];
      $file = $dCreate."-".$_FILES["document"]["name"];
      $file_loc = $_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"];
      $folder="uploads/";
      $final_file = strtolower($file);  

      if ($ftype != "application/pdf") {
       if ($ftype != "")
        echo lang("error-pdf"); // Ausgewähltes Dokument ist kein PDF! 
      }
      else { 
        if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) {
          echo lang("upload-successful"); // Das Document würde hochgelden /* */
          if (file_exists($folder . $_FILES["document"]["name"])) {
          echo lang("exists-error"); // Das Dokument existiert bereits
          }
        }
        else{
          echo lang("no-upload"); // Bitte laden Sie ein Dokument Hoch
        }    
      }
    }
?>
```

The pdf conditional statement and that of move_uploaded_file works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why you first uploading a file then checking if file already exists on the server, I modified a few lines in your code, maybe this can help.

```
<?php
  require("db.php");
  require("functions.php");

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  

      $ftype = $_FILES["document"]["type"];
      $file = $dCreate."-".$_FILES["document"]["name"];
      $file_loc = $_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"];
      $folder="uploads/";
      $final_file = strtolower($file);  

      if ($ftype != "application/pdf") {
       if ($ftype != "")
        echo lang("error-pdf"); // Ausgewähltes Dokument ist kein PDF! 
      }
      else { 
        if (file_exists($folder . $final_file)) {
          echo lang("exists-error"); // Das Dokument existiert bereits
        }
        else if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) {
          echo lang("upload-successful"); // Das Document würde hochgelden /* */
        }
        else{
          echo lang("no-upload"); // Bitte laden Sie ein Dokument Hoch
        }    
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: hey men. I have tried to do that but apparently i require 15reputations for that  https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. Sorry am a newbie but trying to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$folder=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/";
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try the following code

```
if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"]));
```

Currently you are pointing to name not a file !
Good luck